# Should a REST API resource do authorization based on query parameters?

Tags: rest, api-design

For a RESTful API to list resources, I have a method as follows:

`GET - /cars`

It returns a list of a cars, and possibly a pagination token.

I would like to provide a query parameter to filter these results, such as `make`. For example: `GET - /cars?make=Toyota`.

However, due to technical limitations of the system I am working with, this query parameter can only be available to users with a certain authorization, based on their role.

Would it be RESTful to have an API resource such as this that bases its authorization on the request payload, and not just the resource?

An alternative seems to be a separate resource `GET - /cars/filter` that supports the `make` query parameter. However, I'm not sure how to name this resource, since filter is a verb, not a noun.

Comment: Neither the original dissertation about REST nor the RFC 7231 state anything about how the authorization has to be done. To answer the question in the title: It absolutely can. And actually, [filter](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/filter_1) is a noun too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be RESTful to have an API resource such as this that bases its authorization on the request payload, and not just the resource?

Short version: yes, of course.

When a server responds with (for example) `403 Forbidden`, the server is refusing to authorize the *request*.  That might be because the request doesn't include authorization metadata that matches the resource, or it might be for some other reason.

Longer version:

```
GET /cars?make=Toyota
```

For this request, the [request-target](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1), from which we compute the [effective request uri](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.5), *includes the query part*.  In other words, `/cars` and `/cars?make=Toyota` identify *different* resources.

And of course, it may happen in our resource model that Bob is authorized to access `/cars` but not `/cars?make=Toyota` (or vice versa).

It may or may not be straight forward to *implement* those controls in your preferred framework, but as far as the API design is concerned, it's fine.

---

> An alternative seems to be a separate resource GET - /cars/filter that supports the make query parameter.

That's also a perfectly satisfactory option.

> I'm not sure how to name this resource, since filter is a verb, not a noun.

Don't worry about it - REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post

If you try clicking on that link, you'll see that it works exactly as you would expect, even though the spelling includes a verb.